# Protecting prototype.js based XHR requests against CSRF

Tags: ajax, django, prototypejs, scriptaculous, csrf

Django has been updated to 1.3, and in fact ever since 1.2.5, it has extended the scheme to pass a Cross Site Request Forgery protection token to XMLHttpRequests. The Django folks helpfully provide [an example for jQuery](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) to apply a specific header to every XHR.

Prototype (and thus Scriptaculous) have to comply to this scheme, yet I can't find a way to tell prototype to add the X-CSRFToken header. The best would be to do it once in a way that applies it across the app (like for jQuery).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a wild guess but you could try [extending](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/wrap/) the base AJAX class...

```
Ajax.Base.prototype.initialize = Ajax.Base.prototype.initialize.wrap(
    function (callOriginal, options) {
        var headers = options.requestHeaders || {};
        headers["X-CSRFToken"] = getCookie("csrftoken");
        options.requestHeaders = headers;
        return callOriginal(options);
    }
);
```

Comment: I finally had some time to test your solution, and it worked. I just integrated the `getCookie` function inside the anonymous function, like it is in the Django-provided jQuery example.